# Arithmetic Progression question on finding the 25th term

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

In AP, sum of n terms is $\dfrac{3n^2 + 5n}{2}$. Find 25th term.

My work :

$S_n = \dfrac{n}{2}\left({3n + 5}\right)$

$2a + (n-1)d = \left({3n + 5}\right)$

$2a + 24d = 80$

$a + 12d = 40$

13th term is 40.

Bit we need 25th term! Please help

Comment: You have found that the sum is $25$ times the middle term, and the middle of 25 terms is the thirteenth.  Perhaps try to find the sum when the 25th term is the middle one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The $n^{th}$ term is the difference of sum of the first $n$ terms and sum of first $(n-1)$ terms. Mathematically, $$T_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$$

Comment: 1000-924 = 76 is this the answer? Thanks :)